# Angularjs $anchorScroll scrolls everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, anchor-scroll

I have a list with a scroll bar in a window with a scroll bar.

when a user selects an element in the list, I use $anchorScroll to scroll that item to the top of the list.

An unfortunate side effect is that the whole window also scrolls until that item is at the top of the window.

How do I get JUST the list to scroll?

```
var newHash = 'cite' + dp.reference.id;
if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
    // set the $location.hash to `newHash` and
    // $anchorScroll will automatically scroll to it
    $location.hash(newHash);
} else {
    // call $anchorScroll() explicitly,
    // since $location.hash hasn't changed
    $anchorScroll();
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to call the scroll function from angular controller? If you bind the $anchorScroll to the controller does not working as expected?

Comment: Try logging your dp.reference.id value... is it changing?

Comment: Yes I have it in the controller.  The issue is not that the item is not changing, the issue is that the window AND the list scroll.